# How can I stop rounding off shipping charge in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding

When I'm adding Shipping Charge 58.75 to Woocommerce. It's rounding off this to 59.
I want exact Shipping Charge 58.75.

Anyone who has faced this?

Comment: Woocommerce by default would not round the shipping charge, it might be because of some external interfere. Try by deactivating plugins one by one. and double check if any suspicious snippets on your functions.php

Comment: I've not added any plugin which will be rounding off the shipping charge. it's by default functionality.

Comment: No, it is not. WooCoomerce won't round it unless they are not providing option to config so. Please check with the shipping plugin you are using.

Comment: I can't find any solution. I think this is the only Woocommerce which is rounding off shipping price :(

Comment: Give me a temporary access into your site, i can check it for you

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you access

Comment: @RohitGautam Tax is enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/**
 * Get rounding precision for internal WC calculations.
 * Will increase the precision of wc_get_price_decimals by 2 decimals, unless WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION is set to a higher number.
 *
 * @since 2.6.3
 * @return int
 */
function wc_get_rounding_precision() {
    $precision = wc_get_price_decimals() + 2;
    if ( absint( WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION ) > $precision ) {
        $precision = absint( WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION );
    }
    return $precision;
}
```

Please check WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION has been set somewhere else ( maybe in theme )

Here are some constants you can set to alter rounding calculation: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-woocommerce.php#L207-L209. They’d be defined earlier in your wp-config file to change I believe.

Can see here, that WC will mostly use whichever is higher: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/64bcabf0af9a05274d53ec833a4e8c9153509bc4/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L1549-L1553. Either WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION constant, or the number of decimals you have set plus 2.

Answer (score 6):

Goto the WooCommerce > Settings > General Tab and Confirm that the 'Number of decimals' is 2.

[image]

Comment: @RohitGautam Can you update  your question with the list of plugins you haved installed and which theme you are using?

Comment: Problem is I'm unable to set the number of decimal to 2. It only shows 0 always

Comment: @RohitGautam Can you set the WP_DEBUG to true and tell us what the error show?

Comment: You are right. By default, wooCommerce sets Number of Decimals to 2. This was because of a plugin which was rounding everything on the website. I've figured it out recently. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @RohitGautam Glad to help.

Comment: You are the best

Answer (score 4):

You should check your theme files.

Navigate to file in your theme which is calling function to display price.

There might be PHP function *round()*

Documentation: [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Example :

In your theme file there might be code like this:

```
<?php echo round($price); ?>
```

You should change it to:

```
<?php echo $price; ?>
```